# How to return multiple values from XCT Popup to the main page?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have two TimePickers and an Editor in my Popup. I can return Editor value to the main page by clicking on a button on popup:

```
private void Button_Clicked_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dismiss(editor_value.Text);
}
```

and add a label to the main page using this code:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = await Navigation.ShowPopupAsync(new popup01());
    MyStack.Children.Add(new Label { Text = result.ToString()});
}
```

I want to return TimePicker01, TimePicker02, and Editor values to the main page at the same time. I need to have 3 labels in the main page, every time I click the button. label01 for TimePicket01 value, label02 for TimePicket02 value, and label03 for Editor.
I tried to use overload including 3 arguments but `Dismiss` allows just one argument.
Please help me.

Comment: `Dismiss` only accepts a single string argument, so the easiest approach would be to serialize your data as a json string and then deserialize.  Alternately, you could us MessagingCenter or a completion handler

Comment: Thanks for your help. I also found another way. Please look at my answer.

Comment: 1. via property in App.xaml.cs; 2. via local cache/db; 3. [Messaging-Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center). 4. Update the same view model instance. 5. put in one object, [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples)(for multiple objects).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use Arrays. In Popup:

```
private void Button_Clicked_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string timeString01 = DateTime.Today.Add(Time_Start.Time).ToString(Time_Start.Format);
    string timeString02 = DateTime.Today.Add(Time_End.Time).ToString(Time_End.Format);
    string time = string.Join("__", timeString01, timeString02);
    string total = string.Join(",", time, editor_value.Text);
    Dismiss(total);
}
```

And then:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = await Navigation.ShowPopupAsync(new popup01());
    string[] time_text = Convert.ToString(result).Split(',');
    MyStack.Children.Add(new Label { Text = time_text[0].ToString() });
    MyStack.Children.Add(new Label { Text = time_text[1].ToString(), FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label)) });
}
```